# jquery ajax from picasa api doesn't work in IE

Tags: jquery, ajax, internet-explorer

I am using this code to pull pictures urls from picasa:

```
var s = $.dudaGlobal.settings.init;
            var f = $.dudaGlobal.settings.internal;
            var p = $.dudaGlobal.settings.picasa;

            var json_Album_URI = f.picasaUrl
                + "user/" + p.username
                + "?alt=" + "json"
                + "&kind=" + "photo"
                + "&max-results=" + s.images
                + "&hl=" + "en_US"
                + "&fields=" + "entry(media:group,id)"
                + "&thumbsize=" + 104;

            $.ajax({
                type:'GET',
                url:json_Album_URI,
                success:function (data) {
                    $.dudaGlobal.settings.internal.picasaReturnData = data;
                    $('#' + f.imagesCntrID).html(methods.init("createImages"));
                },
                dataType:'json',
                async: true
            });
```

it works in chrome and FF, but not in IE(9 and below). 
I have tried to debug using F12 but no luck.. I'm preety weak with IE.
[here](http://ohadresume.net16.net/Duda/#) is a link to the page

Comment: What happens if, instead of encoding all the arguments yourself in the url, you pass a bare url and pass all the other stuff in a `data : { "alt" : "json", "kind" : "photo" ...}` in the `.ajax` call?

Comment: hi paul, thanks for the fast reply. I've tried what you suggested, but there was no change(worked in ff and chrome but not in ie)

Comment: What happens?  Does it not call the URL, not get a valid response, throw an error?

Comment: I'm not really sure how to debug in IE. the network tab is not showing a url request. debugging the script shows that the script reaches the ajax call.. can you take a look at ohadresume.net16.net/Duda? the script is dudaGallery.js at line 148

Comment: I just tried it with IE 9 and I seem to be getting a good result.  I went into the debugging tools and turned on network capture, and I see what looks like a good JSON response.

Comment: I also put a breakpoint in the success callback, and it gets called with data consisting of "encoding", "feed" and "version" strings, with a ton of stuff in "feed".

Comment: thanks. I got to work by changing  dataType:'json', to  dataType:'jsonp' . and it worked... thanks for the help, paul

Answer (score 0):

I got to work by changing `dataType:'json'`, to `dataType:'jsonp'` . and it worked...